# How to cut a strip of an image using python

Tags: python, image

I have 400 pictures of a wave and I would like to select only a strip (at the same place of the picture) in each pictures and then line them up all together. Is there a way to do it ? I'm using TIFF files and PIL

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [crop](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.crop) method from PIL (or PILLOW)

```
from PIL import Image
import glob

for filename in glob.glob('yourpath/*.tiff'):
    im = Image.open(filename)   
    w, h = im.size
    im.crop((0, 30, w-60, h-30))
```